# Is a mongodb nested array of very long storage appropriate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, chat, limit

> I made a chat system, and all the information in the chatroom is expected to be stored through MongoDB's Document. **Each message sent is appended to the room messages array.**

*The data structure is as follows:*

[image]

This [blog](https://www.morpheusdata.com/blog/2014-12-01-how-to-store-large-lists-in-mongodb) thinks this is the right storage.

But [the official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) says each Document cannot be more than 16 MB

- is the storage design reasonable?
- is there any other better design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on how you will query the data, but I think the design is OK.
Having all the messages inside a chat document will guarantee you to have consistency and keep your chats safe regarding concurrency issues.

About the limit of 16MB, I think it is quite OK.

Anyway, I wouldn't keep the whole history of messages inside the document for performance reasons (it can become very slow to query if you have very busy chatrooms) but I would limit the size of the list of chats to, let's say 100 elements (the most recent ones) and I would use another approach to backup the whole chatroom history.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I should be able to handle the current size limit by transferring a history chat.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to my own question:

> I need to control the length of room messages to be less than 100, similar to the queue, first-in, first-out method.

The sample code for golang is as follows:

```
query := bson.M{
    "room_customer.customer_id": msg.FromUserName,
}
changes := bson.M{
    "$push": bson.M{"room_messages": bson.M{"$each": []model.RoomMessage{
        {    
            Msg:        msgText,
            CreateTime: time.Now(),
        },
    },
    "$slice": -100}},
}
roomCollection.Update(query, changes)
```

*In this way, you can keep the chat record of the conversation room up to 100 messages at all times, I hope it will be helpful for people who encounter similar problems!*